# A riemannian manifold is Hausdorff?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology

The natural topology of a differentiable manifold $M$ is $T_1$, first countable and locally Hausdorff.

We say that a differentiable manifold $M$ is a riemannian manifold if there exists a riemannian metric $g$ defined over $T_pM$ for all $p \in M$.

Also, we can prove that if a manifold $M$ is Hausdorff and second countable, then $M$ admits a differentiable partition of unity and so has a riemannian metric.

By the way, what can we say about the reciprocal? In other words, a riemannian manifold is necessarily a Hausdorff and a second countable space? If no, what would be the counterexample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Riemannian manifold is in fact a metric space!

Given a curve $\gamma$ between two points $x$ and $y$ we can define norm of $\gamma$ as the obvious thing : the integral over $|| (\gamma)'||^2$.
Now define distance between two points as the infimum of norms of all possible curves between the points.

[Just to give you something to look forward to : the harder question is when is a Riemannian manifold complete in the sense of a complete metric space?]

Comment: But a metric space it's not necessarily second countable, right?

Comment: Well, the Riemannian metric is a symmetric positive definite matrix locally (the matrix of the inner product). Now we know we can diagonalise symmetric matrices. So for all intents and purposes the metric looks like the usual Euclidean metric upto some scalar coefficients. Now such metrics are second countable right? I believe you can fill in the details.

Comment: Let say $M$ is the line with two origins and $g$ the standard euclidean metric on $M$. If you calculate the infimum of the length of the curves joining the two origins, it would give you zero.

Comment: Also, you should be integrating $\|\gamma'\|$ instead.